# .net core app parsing decimals in a linux docker container

Tags: c#, parsing, .net-core, cross-platform, globalization

The following code, in a .net core 2.0.0 app works fine when the app is run on the windows development machine. 
When the app is deployed in a linux docker container, it fails with exception message: *System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'*

Why? And what's the workaround?

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var value = "$291.00";
        var valueAsDecimal = decimal.Parse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
        Console.WriteLine(valueAsDecimal);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you don't specify culture when parsing - it parses with current one. Always provide a culture while parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code that worked. I had to manually set the correct culture.
Thanks Richard Schneider and Evk for your comments leading the way.

```
class Program {
    static readonly CultureInfo USEnglish = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var value = "$291.00";
        var valueAsDecimal = decimal.Parse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, USEnglish);
        Console.WriteLine(valueAsDecimal);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It appears that the default culture running on the docker container `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime AS base` is invariant culture:

[image]

Comment: In case you are running an alpine-based dotnet runtime image, you need also to install the ICU cultures package and disable Globalization Invariant Mode in dockerfile:
```RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs  
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false```
Reference: https://andrewlock.net/dotnet-core-docker-and-cultures-solving-culture-issues-porting-a-net-core-app-from-windows-to-linux/

Answer (score 3):

The currency sign is locale specific.  Have you checked what the Culture settings are?

If you always want to use '$' and '.' then use a format provifeer.

```
 var valueAsDecimal = decimal.Parse(
     value, 
     NumberStyles.Any, 
     new CultureInfo("en-AU");
```